# Using Scipy Signal to carry positive balances from previous calculation

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

Is there a way to simulate the follow output using scipy.signal instead of loops?

```
import pandas as pd
df_in = pd.DataFrame({'Generated':[13,8,7,6],'Consume':[8,10,20,5]})
print(df_in)

   Generated  Consume
0         13        8
1          8       10
2          7       20
3          6        5

df_in['balance'] = [5,3,0,1]
```

Where 13 - 8 equals a balance of 5, the 5 is carried balance to the next line and 5+8-10 yeilds a balance of 3.
The three is carried to the next line, 3+7-10 yeilds a negative number, but you can't carry a negative balance. 
So, the next line 0 carry + 6 - 5 yeilds 1 balance.

```
print(df_in)
```

Expected output:

```
   Generated  Consume  balance
0         13        8        5
1          8       10        3
2          7       20        0
3          6        5        1
```

Answer (score 1):

If it wasn't for the requirement to only add to carry if the balance is positive, you could use an accumulator on the difference. This accumulator can be implemented using [`lfilter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html), obtaining the `b` and `a` parameters from the recurrence equation `y[n+1] = y[n] + x[n]`:

```
x = df_in['Generated'] - df_in['Consume']
df_in['balance'] = scipy.signal.lfilter([1], [1,-1], x)
```

Unfortunately adding the carry only if the balance stays positive makes the process non-linear which `scipy.signal.lfilter` is not made to handle. At this point you'd have to resort to using a loop to handle the special case.

Comment: Yes, this so so close.   Any way using signals to on accumulate the positive values?

Comment: Hum... I missed that part of your requirements, which complicates things quite a bit. `scipy.signal.lfilter` can handle linear time invariant signals, which that kind of accumulation isn't. At this point you probably would need to resort to looping over the arrays.